# How to define browser lifecycle in Play Framework's integration tests?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, fluentlenium

Play Framework 2.x supports integration testing backed by FluentLenium library, that has [an ability to control browser lifecycle](https://github.com/FluentLenium/FluentLenium#browser-lifecycle).

But my test cases are extending `play.test.WithBrowser`, not `org.fluentlenium.adapter.FluentTest`. So I guess `@SharedDriver` annotation will not work.

What would be the easiest way to get that feature, in particular, share the same driver for all tests in a class?